# How to convert plural nouns to singular using SpaCy?

Tags: spacy, lemmatization

I am using SpaCy to lemmatize text, but in some special cases I need to keep original text and **just** convert plural nouns to their singular forms. 
Is there a way to tell SpaCy to **only** convert plural nouns to singulars without lemmatizing the whole text (like removing ed, ing...etc) ? Or should I explicitly test each token to check if it is a plural noun to take its lemma?

P.S. Input text is dynamic, so I don't know in advance if the word is a noun or not

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to do this somewhat manually.  Look at the `tag_` field for each word/token and only lemmatize it if it's a `NNS` or `NNPS`.  The full list of tags can be found [here](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html)

Comment: Okay. Please, post your comment as an answer so that I mark it as a correct  answer.

Comment: But that also involves adjusting verb forms, adding determiners, like in `Apples were there` => `An apple was there`, doesn't it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : In my case I am lemmatizing ontology concepts, so I just want to process nouns. for example I want "inverted indices" to become: "inverted index" , not "invert index"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to [bivouac0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4620420/bivouac0)'s comment. I checked tag_ field of each token and retrieved lemma of tokens being tagged as 'NNS' or 'NNPS'

```
processed_text = nlp(original_text)
lemma_tags = {"NNS", "NNPS"}
for token in processed_text:
   lemma = token.text
   if token.tag_ in lemma_tags:
      lemma = token.lemma_
   ...
   # rest of code
   ...
   ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot convert plural nouns to singular nouns using spacy.
You can check whether the token is a plural noun or a singular noun.

If the token's tag is equal to 'NNS', check that token in a dictionary and get the singular form of that token.

Comment: Not true.  The lemma of a noun is its singular form and SpaCy provides lemmatization.  In addition, the `pos` field is the Universal Dependencies tag for the token and does not contain info on plural/singular state.  The `tag` field gives the Penn Treebank tag, which does contain this information.

Comment: Lemmatization is not the correct way of converting plural nouns to singular nouns. For example, the singular form of "radii" is "radius" but the spacy lemmatization shows "radii" as a lemma. Similarly, the singular form of "bacteria" is "bacterium" but the spacy lemmatization shows "bacteria" as a lemma. So it is better to use dictionary.

Comment: And yes, you are right about the tag. The token's tag (NNS, NNPS) should be checked not pos.

Comment: The lemma of a noun is, by definition, its singular form.  Unfortunately the SpaCy lemmatizer doesn't work very well, hence the errors you mention above.

Comment: Yes, the spacy lemmatizer doesn't work very well that is why I mentioned using a dictionary is better to avoid such cases. If the post owner will not face those cases then using lemmatizer is good, like @bivouac0 said.